# pandas: How to get .to_string() method to align column headers with column values?

Tags: python, pandas

This has been stumping me for a while and I feel like there has to be a solution since printing a dataframe always aligns the columns headers with their respective values.

example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'First column name': [1234, 2345, 3456], 'Second column name': [5432,4321,6543], 'Third column name': [1236,3457,3568]})
df_string = df.to_string(justify='left', col_space='30')
```

now when you print df_string, you get the desired formatting:[image: http://i.imgur.com/Xyoy4Op.png]

but when I take the string and view it (in this case, I'm passing the string to a PyQt widget that displays text), this is the output: [image: http://i.imgur.com/a1NcBQA.png]

(this is how the string appears on my console): [image: http://i.imgur.com/WRHEhKB.png]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The result is aligned, you can confirm this by `print(df_string)`.  The problem of pyqt widget is that you are not using a monospace font.

Answer (score 1):

To get around this issue, you can set header=False in the to_string args, then set up a string with the column names with  the right spacing to match the columns of the table.
Print your Columns string before the table and it should all line up. It may take a little tweaking, but it works out albeit a bit hacky.

Example = 'col 1          col2       col3         col4'

Answer (score 1):

This lines up column headers nicely:

```
print(df.to_string())
```

But this prints indices too. If you don't want to print the indices, you can:

```
print(df.to_string(index=False)
```

Problem is, the column headers no longer line up correctly.

So I wrote this hack:

```
blanks = r'^ *([a-zA-Z_0-9-]*) .*$'
blanks_comp = re.compile(blanks)

def find_index_in_line(line):
    index = 0
    spaces = False
    for ch in line:
        if ch == ' ':
            spaces = True
        elif spaces:
            break
        index += 1
    return index

def pretty_to_string(df):
    lines = df.to_string().split('\n')
    header = lines[0]
    m = blanks_comp.match(header)
    indices = []
    if m:
        st_index = m.start(1)
        indices.append(st_index)

    non_header_lines = lines[1:len(lines)]

    for line in non_header_lines:
        index = find_index_in_line(line)
        indices.append(index)

    mn = np.min(indices)
    newlines = []
    for l in lines:
        newlines.append(l[mn:len(l)])

    return '\n'.join(newlines)
```

Which you invoke like this:

```
print(pretty_to_string(df))
```

The code works by calling df.to_string() (where columns are lined up nicely) and calculates the max # of characters taken up by the index column.

It then strips off the indices from each line.