# How to align the output of pandas from command line?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

### I want to align the pandas output in command line prompt on **Windows**.

### This is my code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# -*- coding: gbk -*-
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys
import re
import os

script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
os.chdir(script_dir ) # change to the path that you already know

# dfclient = pd.read_excel(u"ClientManagerNumber.xlsx")
# print(dfclient)
df = pd.read_excel(u"总表-4.26.xlsm")

for i in range(1,18):
    # mask = dfclient[u'序号'] == i
    DataRes = df[[ u"客户"]][df[u'编码'] >= ( i * 100 )][df[u'编码'] < (( i + 1) * 100 )][~df[u'客户'].isnull()].drop_duplicates(subset=[u'客户'], keep='first')
    if not DataRes.empty:
        # print(dfclient[u'姓名'][mask].to_string( index = False))
        print(DataRes.to_string(index = False, header = False))
```

### Here is my excel file like

[image]

### The output in command line is like this:

[image]

### I get the 2 related answers from Stack Overflow

#### [Stack Overflow link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37891620/pandas-how-to-get-to-string-method-to-align-column-headers-with-column-value)

There is a comment in the post that is caused by the  **monospace** font.
I use cmder as the prompt, it already set the monospace

[image]

#### [Stack Overflow link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232013/how-to-set-the-pandas-dataframe-data-left-right-alignment)

This post set the option like this `df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'})` but it doesn't work for me either.

So how to align the output in the command line. I wonder why the **test** and **test2** are not aligned? If I copy the test or test2 row in the excel file and paste it as a new row **test3** For example. The test3 row is still not aligned.

Here is my excel file [link](http://7xpvdr.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/%E6%80%BB%E8%A1%A8-4.26.xlsm)

Comment: this is probably due to spaces, try applying `strip()` method to the strings you're printing like: `print(DataRes.to_string(index = False, header = False).strip())`

Comment: it doesn't work , there is no space in the cell, so strange. `print(DataRes.to_string(index = False, header = False).strip())`